# Filter Slack notifications by watched tags

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams, notifications, slack

I use Slack to get notified about new activity in my Stack Overflow Teams workspace (I don't know if this question is Teams-specific). The configuration for these notifications already has "All Tags" and "Specific Tags" as a filter option (in the Edit Integration menu, see below)

**I would also like to be able to be notified by only tags I am watching**, so I don't have to separately update my watch list and this notification filter list.

This could be another radio button in the "What tags would you like to be notified about?" section:

[image: Edit Slack Integration menu]

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely correct! We are thinking about it; we know it is a problem, and we are thinking of ways to solve this, but it's not going to be resolved in the near term.